# Where four of seven kingdoms meet?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

Where do four of seven Kingdoms meet? This is a clue from the 'scavenger hunt' on the Minecraft server http://westeroscraft.com/ , and I'm *stuck*.

In this treasure hunt, the answer to each clue is a location, which will be where next clue is hidden. For example, an earlier clue was 'where the old bear lives'. That led me to (spoiler)

> the Lord Commander's chambers in Castle Black

Comment: I don't know the answer but there isn't anyplace that the kingdoms actually meet on the map so it's probably a figurative "meeting" like a meeting of the leaders of each house.

Comment: the Old Bear was Jeor Mormont who currently lives nowhere, being dead :) That clue could either refer to Castle Black or Bear Island but both of them are entirely in The North, AFAIK, and I assume there are more than 4 kingdoms represented on The Wall...

Comment: To be clear, these "previous clues" have nothing to do with the question, right? Because as it is, it seems to imply that they are clues to solving the question "where do four of seven kingdoms meet".

Comment: Presumably not, I just shared them for posterity.

Comment: "Presumably"? Were those "clues" actually riddles, and come with an answer? Were they trick questions, or (very basic) straight up knowledge questions? E.g. tree = Weirwood, island = Bear Island/Castle Black. That's a crucial clue in solving this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With some hints from other players, found the fourth clue at the **Inn at the Crossroads**. It's not an exact quadripoint, but the roads north east south and west lead to the North, the Vale of Arryn, the Stormlands and the Riverlands.

The fourth clue is 'Behind the fall where the snow meets the sky'. I know which road to take.

Comment: Sounds like the Eyrie to me.

Comment: The Inn is where the four highways of the Kingdoms meet.  That explanation would be fitting for a riddle.

Answer (score 3):

I would try King's Landing:

- Joffrey Baratheon (even though he was really a Lannister) - Kingdom of the Stormlands
- Tywin, Tyrion, and Cersei Lannister - Kingdom of the Rock
- Oberyn Martell - Kingdom of Dorne
- Margaery Tyrell - Kingdom of the Reach

All of them were present in King's Landing for Joffrey's wedding.

Comment: You can say that about any place where 4 people from different regions have been, though.

Comment: @TLP In this case, though, we're talking about either the current heads of the reigning Houses, or immediate family.